# POST Form Data using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Please note that this question isn't duplicate, I have searched existing related questions.
Hi, I have a REST API that I would be using to post data from my form. I don't want to refresh the page (for which I have seen answers).
My form is :

```
        <form class="t1-form tweet-form
        condensed

        is-autogrow
        "
      method="post"
        data-condensed-text="Compose new Tweet...lll"
      action="/finals/post.php"
      enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <span class="inline-reply-caret">
    <span class="caret-inner"></span>
  </span>

  <div class="tweet-content">


    <div aria-labelledby="tweet-box-mini-home-profile-label"id="tweet-box-mini-home-profile" class="tweet-box rich-editor " contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true" role="textbox"
      aria-multiline="true">


    </div> 
      <input type="submit" value="                   Add Another Note                   " style="float: right;background-color:White;">
    <div class="rich-normalizer"></div>

  </div>

</form>
```

I know I could use a textbox here, but the current div sits nicely with some third party css and so I don't want to change any layout. 
The division in which the content to be posted will be written in :

```
<div aria-labelledby="tweet-box-mini-home-profile-label"id="tweet-box-mini-home-profile" class="tweet-box rich-editor " contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true" role="textbox"
  aria-multiline="true">
```

But this does not have any name that I can access through $_POST["name"] in PHP ?
How to get the contents written in this div ? And then call a php script like post.php without refreshing the page and after post.php has been called the div contents should be reset.
Thanks a lot for your help.

Simpler Version of Same Question : http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/682pG/ I want to use the div (Only the div) for getting input from user and using that input for post request with PHP .

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 place input type in that div ? Please explain a bit. Thanks.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 Thanks. but if i put an input box in div that isn't the solution . The box is the twitter box I took from their page source code . The contents can be written in that div .

Comment: The problem is that you are not using an input tag with a value attribute. When you do use an input tag, the value attribute gets sent up to the server in the parameters. If you don't want to use an input tag, then you can use an ajax call to send data up to the server. Check this out: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.

Comment: I don't get the point about a textbox. Is this about how to include data in the request or how to insert the response into the DOM?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 insert response in DOM

Comment: In that case, why the concern over `$_POST["name"]`? That's server-side.

Comment: @stefvhuynh I want to use a div like in http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/682pG/ (Only the div) for getting the input from user and using it in php .

Comment: @Roamer-1888 http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/682pG/ I want to use the div (Only div) for getting input and then using it in my php script.

Comment: Sorry, I'm thoroughly confused. I can't grasp the scenario.

Comment: That sounds more like including data in the request rather than inserting a response to the DOM... What you're describing is a post request with the contents of the div in the params. You can use `$.ajax { ... method: 'post', data: { 'content': $(yourDiv).html() } ... }`

Answer (score 1):

it is important to note that when you click a button with a type of "submit", it will always trigger a postback..

if you want to do it without refreshing the page. you need to use ajax and prevent the default behavior of the button

```
 <input type="submit" id='btnSubmit' value="Add Another Note" style="float: right;background-color:White;">
```

Script

```
$( "#btnSubmit" ).click(function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
var valueOfDiv = $("#divThatYouCanWriteStuffIn").text();
$.ajax({
    url : 'yourphp.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {content: valueOfDiv},
    success: function(data){
       // do something on the response
    }
});
});
```

PHP code

```
$content = $_POST['content'];
// process it
// echo your response
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but the logic might work:

1) Get the content of the div, either the html or as text using one of the below methods:

```
$("#divThatYouCanWriteStuffIn").html();
```

or

```
$("#divThatYouCanWriteStuffIn").text();
```

2) Inject this as a hidden parameter in the form as soon as the submit button is clicked or use ajax to send the request with the value retrieved from the above method. Something like:

```
$.post( "your-rest-uri.php", {'yourdivcontent': $("#divThatYouCanWriteStuffIn").html()} );
```

3) You can then access this in PHP using:

```
$_POST["yourdivcontent"]
```